# footer background wont work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I was trying to make a simple website for school, but my footer background gets too big.

Here's my HTML

```
<div class="container-fluid">

  <nav>
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Portofolio</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>

  <article>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="images/nature.jpg">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mattis erat, dignissim auctor magna. Cras placerat lorem at fringilla dapibus. Cras lobortis nec eros id congue.
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="images/nature.jpg">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mattis erat, dignissim auctor magna. Cras placerat lorem at fringilla dapibus. Cras lobortis nec eros id congue.
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>
  <article>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="images/nature.jpg">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mattis erat, dignissim auctor magna. Cras placerat lorem at fringilla dapibus. Cras lobortis nec eros id congue.
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="images/nature.jpg">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mattis erat, dignissim auctor magna. Cras placerat lorem at fringilla dapibus. Cras lobortis nec eros id congue.
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="images/nature.jpg">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mattis erat, dignissim auctor magna. Cras placerat lorem at fringilla dapibus. Cras lobortis nec eros id congue.
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="images/nature.jpg">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mattis erat, dignissim auctor magna. Cras placerat lorem at fringilla dapibus. Cras lobortis nec eros id congue.
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="images/nature.jpg">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mattis erat, dignissim auctor magna. Cras placerat lorem at fringilla dapibus. Cras lobortis nec eros id congue.
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="images/nature.jpg">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mattis erat, dignissim auctor magna. Cras placerat lorem at fringilla dapibus. Cras lobortis nec eros id congue.
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="images/nature.jpg">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mattis erat, dignissim auctor magna. Cras placerat lorem at fringilla dapibus. Cras lobortis nec eros id congue.
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="images/nature.jpg">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mattis erat, dignissim auctor magna. Cras placerat lorem at fringilla dapibus. Cras lobortis nec eros id congue.
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="images/nature.jpg">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mattis erat, dignissim auctor magna. Cras placerat lorem at fringilla dapibus. Cras lobortis nec eros id congue.
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <article>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img src="images/nature.jpg">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
      <p>
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mattis erat, dignissim auctor magna. Cras placerat lorem at fringilla dapibus. Cras lobortis nec eros id congue.
      </p>
    </div>
  </article>

  <div class="footer">
    <p> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mattis erat, dignissim auctor magna. Cras placerat lorem at fringilla dapibus. Cras lobortis nec eros id congue. </p>
  </div>

</div>
```

and Here is  my CSS if anybody has any idea on how to fix it  please tell me
i have tried to change sometihngs but my background keeps showing at the top

```
background-color:#d2d8e0;
}

nav {
  background-color: #64f48a;
  float: center;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 350px;
}

nav ul li {
  padding: 0px 50px 20px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}

nav ul li a {
  color: #f0f0f0;
}

nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

article {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 50px;
}

article img {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 50px;
}

article h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}

article p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: red;
}

.footer p {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
}
```

Comment: `background-color:#d2d8e0;
    height: 100%
    margin: 0;
}` You need to fix that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is an issue with the float applied to bootstrap columns, you should wrap your columns with a `row` (See [Grid System](https://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid)).

You could also add a display property to your footer like so or add a column to enclose your footer: `<div class="col-md-12">`.

```
.footer {
  background-color: red;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Working Example** with add `.row` div.

```css
nav {
  background-color: #64f48a;
  float: center;
  padding: 20px 0px 0px 350px;
}
nav ul li {
  padding: 0px 50px 20px 0px;
  display: inline-block;
}
nav ul li a {
  color: #f0f0f0;
}
nav ul li:hover {
  background-color: black;
}
article {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 50px;
}
article img {
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 50px;
}
article h1 {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 20px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
article p {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 15px;
}
.footer {
  background-color: red;
}
.footer p {
  text-align: center;
  color: #fff;
  padding: 50px 10px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">

    <nav>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Services</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Portofolio</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>

    <article>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/000/fff">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mattis erat, dignissim auctor magna. Cras placerat lorem at fringilla dapibus. Cras lobortis nec eros id congue.
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/000/fff">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mattis erat, dignissim auctor magna. Cras placerat lorem at fringilla dapibus. Cras lobortis nec eros id congue.
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/000/fff">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mattis erat, dignissim auctor magna. Cras placerat lorem at fringilla dapibus. Cras lobortis nec eros id congue.
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/000/fff">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mattis erat, dignissim auctor magna. Cras placerat lorem at fringilla dapibus. Cras lobortis nec eros id congue.
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/000/fff">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mattis erat, dignissim auctor magna. Cras placerat lorem at fringilla dapibus. Cras lobortis nec eros id congue.
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/000/fff">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mattis erat, dignissim auctor magna. Cras placerat lorem at fringilla dapibus. Cras lobortis nec eros id congue.
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/000/fff">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mattis erat, dignissim auctor magna. Cras placerat lorem at fringilla dapibus. Cras lobortis nec eros id congue.
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/000/fff">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mattis erat, dignissim auctor magna. Cras placerat lorem at fringilla dapibus. Cras lobortis nec eros id congue.
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/000/fff">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mattis erat, dignissim auctor magna. Cras placerat lorem at fringilla dapibus. Cras lobortis nec eros id congue.
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>

    <article>
      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/000/fff">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mattis erat, dignissim auctor magna. Cras placerat lorem at fringilla dapibus. Cras lobortis nec eros id congue.
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/000/fff">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mattis erat, dignissim auctor magna. Cras placerat lorem at fringilla dapibus. Cras lobortis nec eros id congue.
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>
    <article>

      <div class="col-md-4">
        <img src="http://placehold.it/150x150/000/fff">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</h1>
        <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mattis erat, dignissim auctor magna. Cras placerat lorem at fringilla dapibus. Cras lobortis nec eros id congue.
        </p>
      </div>
    </article>

  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce sed mattis erat, dignissim auctor magna. Cras placerat lorem at fringilla dapibus. Cras lobortis nec eros id congue.</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're planning to put a sticky footer at the bottom, you'll need need to add a bottom padding to the body so that it pushes the footer down. You'll also need to make sure you actually set a height on the footer.

If you want to learn more about how to do this, check out this post:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Answer (score -1):

Remove the `padding-bottom: 200px;` from the `.footer p`

Comment: I have removed the padding but the background color sticks to the top

Comment: @Loriwayne the css that you gave us is not complete ( in the question post ) ! First, please edit and prove it